# "Import * as" not working after upgraing some css related loaders

Tags: reactjs, webpack-5, css-loader, mini-css-extract-plugin, postcss-loader

I upgraded the following packages to their latest versions:

| package name | current version in project | upgraded version(latest version) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| mini-css-extract-plugin | 0.8.2 | 2.8.0 |
| postcss-browser-reporter | 0.5.0 | 0.7.0 |
| postcss-import | 11.1.0 | 16.0.1 |
| postcss-loader | 4.3.0 | 8.1.0 |
| postcss-nested | 3.0.0 | 6.0.1 |
| postcss-reporter | 5.0.0 | 7.1.0 |
| css-loader | 3.5.3 | 6.10.0 |

These upgrades were done as part of webpack 5 upgrade. After this I can see that `import * as css from './some-file.css'` is not working.

When I convert it to `import css from './some-file.css'` its working properly. Can someone help in understanding why `import * as css from './some-file.css'` is not working anymore.

Answer (score 0):

In webpack 4 and earlier, when you used `import * as css from './some-file.css'`, it would import an object containing all the styles from the CSS file. However, starting from webpack 5, this behavior has been changed.

In webpack 5, when you use `import * as css from './some-file.css'`, it treats the CSS file as a module by default, and the styles are accessed through the default export of the module. This means you should use `import css from './some-file.css'` to get the default export (which contains the styles).

In webpack 4:

```
import * as css from './some-file.css';
```

In webpack 5:

```
import css from './some-file.css';
```

**This change was made to align with the ES module specification and provide a more consistent and predictable way to work with CSS modules.**